# MySQL: DELETE didn't shrink DB size, nor table size

Tags: mysql, innodb, delete

In `mydatabase`, there is a table `table1` with almost 8M row, after deleting around 7M rows from the table, the size of the DB and the table itself remains the same.

Table size:

```
+---------------------------------------------+-----------+
| Table                                       | Size (MB) |
+---------------------------------------------+-----------+
| Table1                                      |     96000 |
```

Delete query:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE foo < 'boo'; 
Query OK, 7809000 rows affected (43.25 sec)
```

Size after deleting the data:

```
+---------------------------------------------+-----------+
| Table                                       | Size (MB) |
+---------------------------------------------+-----------+
| Table1                                      |     96000 |
```

Any idea why deleting the data from this table didn't decrease the database size?

Server version: 5.7.19-17-log Percona Server (GPL)

Comment: BTW, What version of MySQL is this ???

Comment: Server version: 5.7.19-17-log Percona Server (GPL), Release 17

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no auto cleanup of fragmentation on deleting table rows from an InnoDB table..

You have to defragment the table manually.

## METHOD #1

You can run the following

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE table1;
```

which will execute the following fotr you

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ENGINE=InnoDB;
ANALYZE TABLE table1;
```

This might lock the table if you still have a lot of rows (this requires downtime). Once done, the table will be smaller. Make sure you have enough diskspace for the table rebuild.

## METHOD #2

If you cannot afford the downtime, you will have to use [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html) to defrag the table. I just mentioned in a recent post : [Can I disable binlogs to save space temporarily](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/281289/can-i-disable-binlogs-to-save-space-temporarily/281293#281293)

Comment: For method1, this won't cause any loss in the remaining data, isn't it?

Comment: @Eng7 As I mentioned in my answer,  ‘ This might lock the table if you still have a lot of rows (this requires downtime).’ Any data loss would be due to nor being able to read from or write to the table. Method 1 requires downtime after business hours and all nightly logging:reporting I’d done.

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways to delete 'most' of a table.  Perhaps the best is

```
SET @@innodb_file_per_table = ON; -- if this is not already on  (optional)

CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;
INSERT INTO new
    SELECT * FROM real
        WHERE ... -- the rows you want to _keep_;
RENAME TABLE real TO old,
             new TO real;
DROP TABLE old;
```

More techiques:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

If this will be a recurring task, see the partitioning suggestion in that link.